# After installing Radeon FX 480 Nitro+ Pc will shoot down when playing games

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, shutdown, amd-radeon, overheating

so i bought Sapphire Nitro+ Radeon 8x 480 OC 8GB GDDR5 GPU and it arrived today. I replaced my Nvidia 750Ti with it and turned the PC on. All nice and good. I proceeded to install drivers directly from AMD website. PC restarted and I turned it back on.

Being happy, first thing I did is put on GTA V and shoved all the graphics settings to High/.very high where possible. The game used only 3023MB of VideoMemory out of over 8000 available. The computer crashed after like 45 seconds

I did put the requirements on minimum. Still the PC crashed.

**My spec:**

AMD FX(tm)- 8320 Eight-Core Processor 3.50 GHZ

16GB RAM

Gigabyte GA 78LMT USB3 motherboard

graphics card mentiond above

ACE A-650BR

[image]

**WHAT DO I KNOW**

PC works fine when not playing the games, pc dies instantly when playing the games. I opened Watch Dogs, and it died on initial loading screen!

The motherboard gets  very hot (physically. When you touch it around processor, it burns you)

Also it doesnt restart itself but it turns itself off and I cant just use the power button to put it back on. I have to unplug the power cable first and plug it back in to put it back on.

I did download HW Monitor (dont know if its any good) but I dont understand the numbers really:

[image]

From what i have read over the net it is probably the Power supply, but I did check before buying and 650 W is apparentely totally enough. Different tests online by people who i believe know what they are doing showed this cards TDP to be 185.

I apprecieate any help guys, Ive spent 250 quid on the card :( and I thought I wont have to spend more on other parts.

Comment: Yes;  Your problem is indeed the power supply.

Comment: and are you sure ? and how ?

Comment: I am 100% sure; 20 years of experience

Comment: Thank you, can you recommend me one that would definitely solve the problem? Do i need more watts? or is the one I have just crap ?

Comment: You have a cheap power supply.  I suggest any `80+ PLATINUM` PSU.  I suspect the problem is the +12 Rail by the way.  Even the cheapest `80 PLUS GOLD` has 54A on the +12 Rail.

Comment: Yes I just saw prices of ebay I see it costs £17 

Would this one be enough?: Sorry for bothering you but You did say you have 20 years experience and I have none
http://www.awd-it.co.uk/evga-600w-80-plus-certified-psu-power-supply.html?gclid=COKesqXYzNECFYIL0wod99AJdA

Comment: I will not confirm any specific PSU will work nor will I suggest any specific PSU.  You wanted my recomendation and I provided my recomendation, an class of PSU, I personally would trust.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, 80 PLUS is a good indicator of a quality power supply, but it doesn't have to be Platinum.  It's also important to verify on [plugloadsolutions.com](https://www.plugloadsolutions.com/80PlusPowerSupplies.aspx) since some are falsely claiming it, or making up something deceptively similar like "80+".

Comment: @Jason - I just went with the Amps on the +12v.  I sort of indicated what I thought was a target, 54A, and your right it doesn't have to be Platinum but you also get what you (do or do not) pay for.